# setting jetty9 in windows 7

Tags: java, windows, jetty

I'm trying to run the server but does not appear the applications that are in demo- base,

https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/uGuFSW8qTeeoaStdgXmq
https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/BvxaEYDZRMKetH7qUNc9

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please add the contents of you screenshots *as text* to your post.

Comment: You should copy and paste the actual text in your screenshots to your post here. In addition, you should reference the 'demo- base' you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to start from the sub-directory:

```
  $ cd demo-base
  $ java -jar ../start.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Best to learn maven for EASE development and deployment.
http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html

maven will help to AUTO download the needed dependency for setting up jetty and also simpler config.

$ mvn jetty:run

**Use maven to deploy using this pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.youcompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>runjetty</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>        
    </properties>
    <build>        
        <plugins>  
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.10.v20150310</version>
                <configuration>
                    <connectors>
                        <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                            <port>8080</port>
                            <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
                            <responseHeaderSize>16192</responseHeaderSize>
                        </connector>
                    </connectors>
                    <webApp>
                        <contextPath>/yourWebApp</contextPath>
                    </webApp>
                    <war>C:/pathto/yourwebapp.war</war>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```